# How to allow non-admin user to write to registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SWname\Licenses

Tags: c#, windows-installer, registrykey

I have a software deployed using Windows Installer.

On Windows XP, When I use non-admin user to install the software package, it asks for administrator's right which is correct.
Then I click run as administrator and wait for the installation finish.

Then if I (non-admin user) want to write to registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SWname\Licenses", the software throws an exception. The access is denied.

I use follows in the source code :

```
RegistryKey rk= Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\"+swName+"\\Licenses", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
```

But still cannot access to the registry key if I am an non-admin user.

How to allow non-admin user have write access to the registry key under my software ? Like adding a license ?

Comment: Use impersonation: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4051/Windows-Impersonation-using-C

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to point out is why do you have a custom action instead of using the Windows Installer Registry table?   A per-machine installation is "managed" or "trusted"  meaning that subsequent repairs/reinstallations will automatically elevate and have permission to update the registry.

You can use the LockPermissions table in Windows Installer to relax the permissions on that registry key.  Assuming it's a safe and appropriate thing to do so.

Comment: I cannot create this license key during installation using windows installer.  This key should be entered by the user manually. Any ways that I can give the permission to write the key for non-admin users ?

Comment: Why not?  Just create a Licenses key with a default value that has null data and then set the permissions on that key.  When the user enters the registry data it'll create an additional registry value.

Comment: Why not change the install to use a license in HKCU? Keep in mind that Windows Installer does not violate security rules. A limited user cannot modify restricted areas of the system just because it's in an install - that would be a huge security hole.  You would need to get admin privilege somewhere.

Comment: The problem is when I create the empty  licence key in install project in visual studio 2005, I cannot find any place to set the permission for that registry key in visual studio 2005.

Comment: We don't want to store the license key in HKCU as it will bring more code to search for the license every time... If I cannot make  non-admin user access to HKLM\software\swname\License  registry key, then maybe in the far future the HKCU is considered.